# Gmail Email Markup Schema and Mailchimp

Tags: gmail, mailchimp, email, google-schemas

I want to add Gmail Email actions to my outbound emails: https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/offer?hl=en

Using mailchimp, I have verified with Mailchimp that the emails are signed by DKIM.

When I view the email headers I send, I see
mailed-by: mail171.suw12.mcsv.net
Signed by: mail171.suw12.mcsv.net

I would expect to see, in order to work with Gmail Actions:
mailed-by: mycompany.net
Signed by: mycompany.net

Typical issues Google rejects submissions include:
1) Email’s domain not authenticated properly (DKIM, SPF).
2) Authenticated domain does not match the “From:” email’s domain.
3) Not enough volume sent to Gmail addresses (need more than 100     emails/day).
4) Spam reputation is too low (too many spam complaints from users/emails qualified as spam).

I have verified 2-4 is not an issue.

Has anyone used Mailchimp successfully to send Gmail actions markup?

Comment: E.g. the confirmation emails from MailChimp are marked up per default (i.e. you can confirm your subscription by using a quick action in the subject line). Are you registered with Google? Also note that Gmail Grid View does not exist anymore.

Comment: Hi, I can't register with Google, as they say my email is not a valid DKIM, hence my question above, as I'm using Mailchimp.         https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/rsvp-action  is the main action I want to invoke, the offer action is just the easiest to test with.

Comment: If 3) is not an issue, your may want to ask the MailChimp support, how you can implement DKIM authentification for your domain, too. As a side effect, this will also remove the "via" note next to your from name in the email view.

Comment: Yep, I was in touch with Mailchimp as we send over 1k a day emails. They verified DKIM is set up correctly, but I suspect their setup does not support Gmail Actions. Has anyone used Mailchimp successfully to send Gmail actions markup?

Comment: @VinnyGlennon users who get started with a new MailChimp account get a email notification with a confirm action button, so I'm sure you can use Gmail markup with MailChimp (https://blog.mailchimp.com/gmails-inbox-actions-work-with-mailchimp). On the registration site (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google) it states  "(order of hundred emails a day minimum to Gmail) for a few weeks at least." So, maybe you could try registering again in a few weeks.

Comment: @Franco their transaction emails may be different from their customers emails. I signed up new account and did not get a confirm action button. I also checked the source code, no mention.      We send out well over a 1k a a day for months, this limit is not an issue